# Use of <result>

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the use of "result" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> The cleaner air will be **resulted** by using the VTB because the VTB
>   has the higher energy efficiency at high flow coefficients than the
>   CTB.

CTB=Constant thickness blade
VTB=Variablethickness blade

Comment: **result** is not a transitive verb, and so it cannot be used in passive constructions (e.g. "be resulted"). *Cleaner air **will result** when using the VTB..*  Or you can make the VTB the subject of your sentence, or use a **using** participle phrase, as in Peter's answer.  You could also say "Cleaner air was **produced** by using the VTB..." since **produce** is transitive.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I'd rather say *Cleaner air will result **from** using the VTB* - but substantially, I agree.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *result from* is another viable option, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of **resulted** is a bit awkward. Better might be

> Using the VTB **resulted in** cleaner air because the VTB has **a** higher energy efficiency at high flow coefficients than the CTB.